# Parsing JSON on PHP with double quote

Tags: php, json

I'm using *json* to post data *from iOS/Android to my server*.

I handle the Post data with those lines :

```
//$json_alert = stripslashes(utf8_decode($_POST["json_alert"]));
$json_alert = $_POST["json_alert"]);
echo $json_alert;
$json = json_decode($json_alert);

$this->id_type = $json->{'alerte'}->{'id_type'};
        $this->note = $json->{'alerte'}->{'note'};
        $this->coordinate = $json->{'alerte'}->{'location'}->{'lat'} . ";" . $json->{'alerte'}->{'location'}->{'long'};
        $this->id_user = $json->{'alerte'}->{'expediteur'}->{'id_user'};
```

The problem is : When I send json with a quote, json_decode fail constantly.

However, when a print json_alert the format seems to be right.

```
echo $json_alert;

**** print ****

{
  "alerte": {
  "note":"It's not \"working\"", //double quote fails in json_decode
  "expediteur":{
  "id_user":"5"
 },
  "location":{
  "lat":"37.785834",
  "long":"-122.406417"
 },
  "id_type":"3"
 }
}
```

What's the solution to parse json even I write double quote ?

**EDIT :** I removed the `stripslashes()` but the problem stay alive

Comment: Dont try to solve a problem of another problem. Solve the original problem

Comment: why dont you just use HTML characters?

Comment: here -> http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: You have `$json_alerte` and `$json_alert`. Is that a typo?

Comment: You're destroying your json data by mangling the json string with stripslashes.

Comment: @thedjnivek: What's the original JSON string you're trying to decode? Please post that.

Comment: @MarcB, not according to the printout, which admittedly could be wrong.

Comment: @Bojangles Oops sorry, but it's just on this post, on my code I have only $json_alert ;)

Comment: @AmalMurali Original post : {
    "id_user" = 5;
    "json_alert" = "{\n  \"alerte\" : {\n    \"note\" : \"voila voila mec 'ton \\\"\",\n    \"expediteur\" : {\n      \"id_user\" : \"5\"\n    },\n    \"location\" : {\n      \"lat\" : \"37.785834\",\n      \"long\" : \"-122.406417\"\n    },\n    \"id_type\" : \"3\"\n  }\n}";
}

Comment: @thedjnivek: It's not even valid. Try validating using an online service such as http://jsonlint.com

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm using NSJSONSerialization:dataWithJSONObject with Objective-C to create this JSON. The original JSON should be right, no ? And this mistake is with no double quote the parsing succeed.. :/

Comment: @AmalMurali The json writing on the "echo" is valid. So why the json_decode() fail ?

Comment: @nickc: stripslashes knows **NOTHING** about json. it'll just remove one set of slashes. a valid json string `{"foo":"this has a \" quote in it"}` is going to to get manngled down to `{"foo":"this has a " quote in it"}` and boom. now it's not json. it's just random garbage.

Comment: @MarcB Not the point.  The author *claimed* he was echoing `$json_alert` which was assigned *after* the original `stripslashes` call and immediately before the `json_decode` call, and what was printed was correctly formed.

Comment: @MarcB when I try an `echo` without doing `stripslashes` before, my `echo` is **NULL** :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using `Base64`.

The note content is encoded on `Base64` and to get the note I do
`$this->note = base64_decode($json->{'alerte'}->{'note'});`

Know I can write everything in the *note content* without worry about the syntax.
It's a alternative solution, not the real correction.

I'm still curious, I'd like to know where the error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a valid JSON string:

```
{"foo":"this string has a single \" double quote in it and a \\ backslash"}
```

`stripslashes()` knows **NOTHING** about JSON syntax. It simply does its job and removes one layer of slashes, giving you:

```
{"foo":"this string has a single " double quote in it and a \ backslash"}
                                 ^--- bare quote, now terminating the string early
                                                            ^--- bare escape
```

and boom, you no longer have a JSON string. You've got some random "garbage" that will cause `json_decode()` to fail.

**UNLESS** your PHP install is a horribly/stupidity ancient and/or badly configured, you should **NOT** have to remove any slashes, because magic_quotes_gpc should be OFF and/or utterly removed from PHP.

Comment: But when I `echo $json_alert` after, I have a correct JSON Format and if I don't use `stripslashes()`the echo content is null

Comment: echo the $_POST value directly, compare it to what you get after stripslashes. YOu'll probably find that your system has magic_quotes turned off, meaning there are **NO** extra slashes in your raw json data, and you are DESTROYING it by doing stripslashes anyways.

Comment: FYI I use MAMP to simulate my server. I try to `echo` the original value and I tell you the result.

Comment: The original value is : "alerte" : {
    "note" : "What's up \"dad\"",
    "expediteur" : {
      "id_user" : "5"
    },
    "location" : {
      "lat" : "37.178181",
      "long" : "-96.054581"
    },
    "id_type" : "4"
  }

Comment: So yes, you only have the JSON-required escapes in there, and stripslashes is removing them, leaving you with invalid json.

Comment: Yes but the problem stay here.. I can't parse this JSON. I'm trying to encode the note content with html characters

Comment: I solved my problem by using base64 on the note content. It's more easier and no more problems with special characters. But I'm still curious, I'd like to know where the error occurred.